# How do I write a route that goes from one message queue to another with outbound request inbetween?

Tags: apache-camel

So the problem that I am facing right now requires us to do the following:

1. We receive a message as an XML on a message queue
2. We do some basic parsing on the XML
3. We send a request with some information pulled from the XML off to another server
4. We wait for the response from that request
5. We create a new XML based on information from the response and in the initial XML
6. We put that new XML on a different message queue

We are using Camel on the team, and none of use have ever really used it before. From what I have read and looked into, it sounds like this is something that Camel should support, but I don't know how we configure the route to make it work.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in short, something like this...

```
from("activemq:queue:inbound")
    .process(new PreProcessor())   //parses inbound message and prepares server request
    .to("http://someserver")       //could be any request/reply endpoint
    .process(new PostProcessor())  //parses the response and prepares the outbound message
    .to("activemq:queue:outboud");
```

Comment: Awesome, I think that is what we are going to want to do. One question though, for putting the request out to SomeServer do we just put the request in the message that goes into the exchange? Or is there something else? Or can you point me at documentation that I need to read for that?

Thank you so much!

Comment: sure, depends on the technology you are using to communicate with the other server.  If you are using HTTP, then see http://camel.apache.org/http.html, otherwise see this list of other natively supported interfaces (http://camel.apache.org/components.html).  Also, you can just use a Processor or Bean and do any proprietary integration you need...